# Best way to force SSL for certain controllers?

Tags: php, lithium

I'd like to force SSL for certain controllers, and remove SSL for everything else. I had a snippet some time ago in the _init() of a custom Controller class, it didn't work as I had hoped:

```
$ssl = $this->request->is('ssl');

$forceSecured = in_array($this->request->controller, array('Orders', 'Customers'));

//remove SSL for non-ssl pages
if ($ssl && !$forceSecured) {
    return $this->redirect(Router::match(
                    $this->request->params,
                    $this->request,
                    array('absolute' => true, 'scheme' => 'http://')
            )
    );
}

// Force ssl on for ssl pages
if (!$ssl && $forceSecured) {
    return $this->redirect(Router::match(
                    $this->request->params,
                    $this->request,
                    array('absolute' => true, 'scheme' => 'https://')
            )
    );
}
```

I'm supporting a legacy application, so I've got multiple hard-coded routes defined. I'm sure that I could use a handler in the Router::connect, but I'd rather do the check on all requests. Would continuation routes be the way to go here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things: (1) you can't return a `Response` object from `_init()` (which is what `redirect()` returns), and (2) you have a subtle design problem. I'd suggest doing it like this:

```
protected $_secure = false;

public function __invoke($request, $params, array $options = array()) {
    if (!$this->_secure && !$request->is('ssl')) {
        return parent::__invoke($request, $params, $options);
    }
    return $this->redirect(Router::match($request->url, $request, [
        'absolute' => true, 'scheme' => 'https://'
    ]));
}
```

**Observations:**

- You're redirecting to the same URL but for the protocol, no point in redundantly generating the URL
- The decision of whether a particular controller gets redirected lives with the controller; this gets more important as you get to the point (and you likely *will* get to the point) where it's not just per-controller but per-action

Comment: Returning the `Response` object is where I got myself into trouble. Also, I guess I didn't abstract it enough.

Side note, the `$this->redirect line` is missing a closing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Why let it get to the application?  Use htaccess rewrites if you are cathcing specific routes to force ssl.

Ssl is a transmission protocol detail and has nothing to do with your site code, let apache (or nginx) handle those details. Separation of responsiblity to what best to handle things.

If you provide exac urls you want to catch I am sure somone could help with the rewrite condition logic

Comment: I agree with this a bit, but think about link generation and reverse routing. It's inefficient for the application to output redirects or http links that then have to be redirected again by the web server.

Comment: @rmarscher when the application issues a 30x redirect, it still another request round trip.  I say cut the application out completely and let it be done by apache, before the application ever sees it nevermind routes it.

Comment: Disagree. The decision of whether or not to secure a page is a business decision. (1) Rewrite rules don't provide an abstraction capable of expressing that in business terms, and (2) you already have a place for business logic: controllers; why split it up? The level of optimization you're talking about is *rarely* a valid concern.

Comment: Normally I'd agree with @Ray, but Nate Abele is right. In my case, it's a business decision, which should live in code. Also, it's easier to deploy in code than an apache or nginx config.